# Purpose of fittings at the bottom of suspension fork?

Tags: disc-brake, fork, suspension, adjustment, brake-noise

I have a question about the suspension fork on my mountain bike.

There is a hex socket at the bottom of the right fork leg.

There is a normal bolt head at the bottom of the left fork leg.

Are these adjustments, and if so what do they do?

I have a question about my front forks.   When braking the bike shudders.
Hoping someone might watch the youtube video and answer my question.

Comment: What is the make and model of the fork?

Comment: I'm not going to watch a video before I know what the question is. Put your question in writing. And put in a meaningful title while you're at it.

Comment: thank you for the response.  i made the video because it was much easier for anyone to see what i was talking about

Comment: @richardgreaves What is the brand and model of your fork ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it is a fastener and does not do anything useful except hold the fork together.

The right side of the fork usually contains the damper, with various adjustments.  Usually, a fork has at least a rebound, but more advanced forks have one or more of separate compression and hi speed/low speed rebound adjustment (along with the internal adjustment's that can be done with spacers and oil viscosity). Often these adjusters are on the bottom of the fork leg.  This fork appears to have an adjustment knob on the top. As it has no obvious branding, and cable disc brake, it is unlikely to have premium features, meaning the hex bolt is more than likely just a bolt.

You could try turning it. If it is an adjustment, it will probably turn on both directions and will feel less like a bolt and more like the knob on top.  Don't remove it if it is a bolt - a good chance if you do you will spill oil, and the last thing you want is to is spill the oil from a fork you do not have service information for.

Braking shudder could be coming from the headset, worn bushings in the fork, axle or brakes.  With the front brake on, push the bike forward and back and feel for movement in the headset and fork stanchions.  Is the wheel correctly fitted (axle snugged up tight)? Is the brake caliper and disc correctly fitted?  Have a search here how to check for these things.

Comment: thank you for the response.  i gave it 10 turns clockwise and nothing happened.  the resistance doesn't change on the bolt like it isn't doing anything and the forks don't feel any different.  thanks for the advice though and i do appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from the video what fork exactly you have, but the bottom of a fork leg is where the damping adjuster is usually located.

To verify that turn it as far clockwise as it will go, but remember to stop as soon as you feel resistance and do not go any further. Then pump the fork and note how quickly it returns to the equilibrium position. Now turn the adjuster all the way in the other direction and pump the fork again. You should notice a big difference in how fast the fork moves between the two extremes.

Comment: thank you so much for the response.  I tied turning it as i mentioned in the video but this time i gave it a good 10 turns clockwise and nothing happened.  it doesn't seem to give any more resistance as the turns ad up.

Comment: @richard greaves Sometimes a fork's rebound adjuster will be on the bottom of the right fork leg. There's two general designs, one where a piece is attached to a cap. The piece will fit up thru a hole in the bolt and the cap will have some sort of friction fit onto the head of the bolt to keep it in place but also be able to turn around on the bolt head. The piece up into the fork leg interfaces with the rebound needle and turning the exterior cap turns the rebound needle.  The other design brings the needle from the inside to the outside where a cap is somehow interfaced with needle to adjust

Comment: Is there a central hole all the way thru the bolt on right fork leg?

Comment: no i don't see a hole